# List of List C# count jumps when adding and Element at a certain row

Tags: c#

i am trying to implement an adjacency list using

```
List<List<int>>
```

but every time i add an new element in a certain index the whole inner list counts jumps 
for example:

```
List<List<int>> neighbours = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> emptyList= new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    neighbours.Add(emptyList); 
    neighbours[i].Add(0);
}
```

everything is going ok at this point and `list[anyIndex].count=1;`
but when i do that

```
 neighbours[3].add(1);
```

all `list[anyIndex].count` jump to 6 
any idea what is happening ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

All lists are actually one and the same, because you add `emptyList`.

Instead you need to create [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator):

```
neighbours.add(new List<int>());
```

If you wanted to use something readable like `emptyList`, you could create a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)(C#7):

```
List<int> emptyList() => new List<int>();
// ...
neighbours.Add(emptyList()); // creates always a new now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
List<List<int>> neighbours = new List<List<int>>();
for(int i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
     neighbours.Add(new List<int>()); 
     neighbours[i].Add(0);
 }

for(int i=0 ; i < 5 ; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(neighbours[i][0]);
 }
```